# How to run batch file in Inno Setup, while showing progress as each command gets executed

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-setup-v6

> EDIT: I can't find the solution but Martin's method looks like only
>   solution for this situation.

I am trying to execute about 30-40 command line parameters. I don't want to separate commands with "&&" because it looks very complex all of these codes in one line.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder1"" && mkdir ""{app}\Folder2"" && mkdir     
""{app}\Folder3"" mkdir ""{app}\Folder4"" && mkdir ""{app}\Folder5"" && mkdir ""{app}\Folder6"" && mkdir ""{app}\Folder7"""
```

As you can see it looks so complex.

> (`mkdir` command is example. Each commands are different in my
>   project.)

How can I achieve it?

**I can use .cmd or .bat file and run it but don't want it because I want to see progress bar on installer. My commands takes some time to finishing executing.**

Waiting for helps, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to do any ot that the way you are. Use PascalScript and do it all directly from a code block in the installer itself.

Comment: There are many existing posts here about creating folders in InnoSetup using PascalScript. Have you made any effort to find them yet?

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can do a whole lot of things in PascalScript in Inno Setup. I don't know what else you're trying to do, but again there are **lots** of examples of scripting in Inno Setup on this site. Have you made **any effort at all** to search for them yet?

Comment: You wrote that you do not want to use a batch file, because you want to see a progress bar. Yet you put all commands to a single command line, so the effect is the same as if you use the batch file. You won't see any progress. It's *one command*. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: This is why i am asking how can i avoid using "single command line"? It looks so complex. How can i line break between codes etc.

Comment: What solution you cannot find? What are you missing?

Comment: To read better this comment: http://prntscr.com/og4s16

if exist a.txt (
if exist b.txt (
copy x y
copy z y
copy c y
)
)

For example i can't write this cmd code block in inno-setup with multiple lines. i need to put in if exist inside an if exist. I need to write like this to make it work;

if exist a.txt ( if exist b.txt ( copy x y && copy z y && copy c y && ) )

This might look simple but my project is more complex than this example codes so writing in 1 line is a nightmare for this situation.

Comment: 1) `if exist a.txt if exist b.txt copy x y` 2) `if exist a.txt if exist b.txt copy z y`, etc. You can use Inno Setup preprocessor to avoid repeating the code.

Comment: I downloaded inno setup preprocessor but i don't exactly understand how it can help me about avoiding repeating codes?

Comment: Sorry, but this is getting too broad. If you want our help, you need to post a good question in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for that. I think i need to ask another question about how to minimize code using with inno setup preprocessor.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute multiple commands standalone, add separate entry to the `[Run]` section for each command:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder1""
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder2""
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder3""
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder4""
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder5""
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder6""
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c mkdir ""{app}\Folder7""
```

---

Though for creating folders, there's a dedicated [`[Dirs]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection):

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\Folder1"
Name: "{app}\Folder2"
Name: "{app}\Folder3"
Name: "{app}\Folder4"
Name: "{app}\Folder5"
Name: "{app}\Folder6"
Name: "{app}\Folder7"
```

Comment: Looks like only solution is this. But this is not exactly what i was looking for. For example check out this;
if exist asd.txt (
copy asd.txt "folder1"
mkdir folder2
copy "folder1\asd.txt" "folder1\..\folder2" )

see? i need to write all this lines in same line to execute it on inno setup. but in bat or cmd file i can put a ine break so code will look less complex.
i cant write if exist command under multiple [Run] commands

Comment: Is there an option to skip next line to continue reading code in inno setup Run section? Like putting a character " \ "

Comment: Of course that you can use `if exist` in Inno Setup. But you have to use it for each command separatelly, if you want the progess bar.